# Which PHPMailer prop controls the sender email in the email header?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm getting an error from jQuery with a 404 to my mail.php (I checked the path and it seems correct)

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require("../includes/libraries/phpmailer/PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php");
require("../includes/libraries/phpmailer/PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php");
require("../includes/libraries/phpmailer/PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php");

$server_email = 'myemail@outlook.com';
$pass = '123456';

$full_name  = $_POST['full_name'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];


$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
$mail->Host = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = $server_email;
$mail->Password = $pass; 


$mail->FromName = $full_name;   
$mail->From =  $email;  
$mail->setFrom($server_email, $full_name );
$mail->addAddress($server_email); 
$mail->addReplyTo($email); //email that it will be replied to

$mail->Subject = 'Subscription submitted by ' . $full_name . '.';
$mail->Body = "
  Name: $full_name<br><br> 
  Email: $email<br>
";

if(!$mail->send())
  {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
  }
?>
```

Right now, my email (the outlook one) comes up in the header of the email next to the Sender's Name. The `addReplyTo` actually does give me the gmail address to reply to, so that's great. But having my email show on the sender header is confusing. See the image below

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I thought I tried that. Let me give it one more try. Oh actually it is already in my code. Yeah didn't work

Comment: `$mail->setFrom($server_email, $full_name );` is what is setting the From address

Comment: @aynber I thought so but it throws an error `SendAsDenied; myemail@outlook.com not allowed to send as anotheremail@outlook.com`

Comment: Sounds like Outlook has rules in place that you can only send as the account you're logged in with. You most likely won't be able to change the From email address.